# sh split value into variables

Tags: shell

This works on the command line, but not in a script.

```
read -r local_temperature system_mode preset running_state current_heating_setpoi
nt <<< $(thermostat)
```

> Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Can it be done in a script? Seems a bit crap to use `cut` five times but that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: What is the shebang in the script?

Comment: <<< is a zsh operator. Now recognised by a few other shells, but not valid sh syntax

Comment: `#!/bin.sh` and `#!/bin/bash` gives the same error.

Comment: << heredoc is standard in sh though

Comment: Sounds like it's impossible, then, and it has to be muleiple `cut`s.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough - How do you run the script? `sh myscript` ? If so, that might be the cause it doesn't work. Run it as `./myscript` or `bash myscript` (assuming shebang is either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`)

Comment: Your `#!/bin.sh` is (almost certainly) invalid and should probably be `#!/bin/sh`. But not for this question as `<<<` isn't valid for `sh`

Answer (score 2):

For dash (on Ubuntu) you can use traditional heredoc (`<<`) instead of herestring:

```bash
read -r local_temperature system_mode ... <<END # END must be unquoted
$(thermostat)
END
```

But for busybox I get a spurious 'not found' error with what seems to be variable garbage.

If (1) the output from the command does not contain glob characters or you have turned glob off with `set -f` or similar and and (2) you are not running in a script that was passed parameters you need in any subsequent command, you can (ab)use the positional parameters:

```bash
set -- $(thermostat); local_temperature=$1; system_mode=$2; ...
```

This doesn't do 'all words after n-1 are combined in the last=nth var' like `read` but you can approximate that with e.g.

```bash
a=$1; b=$2; c=$3; shift 3; d=$* 
# d gets all words after the first 3 but not the original delimiters e.g. multiple spaces
```